# How to change url after spring controller invocation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I have approximately following controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String foo(RedirectAttributes  redirectAttributes, Model model) {
   //logic
   return bar(model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)      
public String bar (Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("value","magicValue")
   return "myJsp";
}
```

my aim that after `/foo`  invocation url was changed with `bar`

method `bar` shouldn't be broken.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In method `foo` you can do:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:bar", modelName, model);
```

But this will add additional request to a server. It will also put the model values in the URL which is not always desirable

Comment: at this case model.addAttribute("value","magicValue") will be skipped

Comment: ModelAndView have not constructor which accepts model

Comment: **@param modelName name of the single entry in the model** I didn't caught it

Comment: I think I should use **asMap()** method from **Model** class